# Setting a threshold for multiple files in directory

Tags: awk, sed

I have a list of files in a  directory. For instance the below files are the names of each file with the first line displayed (it has several other lines in each file that is not of importance).

*Group1*:

```
8 325
quick brown fox jumped
Over the lazy dog
```

*Group2*:

```
8 560
There is more content here
```

*Group3*:

```
7 650
```

I would like to read the first line of each file and check if the first value  is equal to 8 and the second value is more than 500. If this condition is satisfied, print the name of the file into a new textfile.

*Result*

```
Group2
```

I tried using

```
for f in *.Group; 
do head -n1 *.Group > new-file;
done
```

This gives me a file with header names and the first line of each file in the directory

```
=> Group1 <=
8 325

=> Group2 <=
8 560

=> Group3 <=
7 650
```

Now, I want to filter the files based on the threshold, but am not sure how to convert all the headers into first columns and the corresponding values into second column. Then it is easy to apply the threshold and filter the file. Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: So are your files called e.g. `Group1` or `Group1.Group`?

Comment: Group1, group2,.. and so on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR==1 && $1==8 && $2>500{print FILENAME}' *.Group > Result
```

Explanation:

```
# FNR contains the number of line of the current(!) input
# file. Check if the conditions are met and print the filename
FNR==1 && $1==8 && $2>500 {
    print FILENAME
}
```

The above solution should work with any version of `awk`. If you have GNU `awk` you can take advantage of the `nextfile` expression. Using it you skip the remaining lines of an input file once the first line has been processed:

```
# Check if the conditions are met and print the filename in that case
$1==8 && $2>500 {
    print FILENAME
}

# Skip the remaining lines in the current file and continue
# with the next file
{
    nextfile
}
```

Comment: So I checked the number of fields in the first line of the file awk -F '' '{print NF}' Group1 and it displays as 6, so in this case the solution might be bit different because they are not just two separate fields.

Comment: `-F ''` splits the line into into separate characters. `Group1` has 6 characters, that's correct. So what do you mean?

Comment: Glad to hear that!